# How to get a file's path when dragging from anywhere in explore

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I want to design an app using C# to have a container to let me drag a .xml file from anywhere inside the Windows Explorer.  Then, get the path of this file, call a function to use .bat file to deal with this file.

For example, I drag Super.xml file from Windows Explorer to my app, and then the app will use a bat file to deal with the xml file I just Dragged in. Then I can use a notepad++ or IE page to output the file which has been executed by bat file.

The cmd of using this bat file is:    x:\sample.bat super.xml

Comment: See MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And, What is the question? How to detect drop, how to start batch file, how to receive parameters in batch, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.  It will let you drag and XML file to the form, and then the nodes of the XML file are displayed.  You can easily modify this to do what you're describing.
You may also find this link useful: [Drag and Drop Text Files From Windows Explorer To Your Windows Form Application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=192&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlDragDropExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AllowDrop = true;
            this.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragEnter);
            this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(Form1_DragDrop);
        }

        private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] filePaths = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            foreach (string fileLoc in filePaths)
            {
                var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileLoc);
                foreach (var element in xdoc.Root.Descendants())
                {
                    textBox1.Text += element.Name + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  It's really really useful to me.